# how to console.log object in one line

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to modify this object

```js
const myObject = { "first": ["x","y", "z"], "second": ["a", "b"], "third": ["c"] }
const string = "String!";
const count = () => {
  const result = Object.entries(myObject ).forEach(([key, value]) =>
    console.log(`${key} ${value.length > 1 ? ("x " + value.length) : ""} (${value})`)
  );
  return result;
};
count();
```

I got here

```
first x 3 (x, y, z)
second x 2 (a, b) 
third (c)
```

I would like to get this output how I can put it in one line and string before? or should I use new function for it?

```
String! first x 3 (x, y, z) – second x 2 (a, b) - third(c)
```

Comment: Instead of logging the data inside the forEach, just append the data to your ```string``` variable. Then log the variable at the end.

Answer (score 0):

To get the output you've said you want, you have to:

1. Use `map` to build an array of the entries, rather than outputting those strings.
2. Add `string` to the beginning.
3. Turn the array into a string with `" - "` between the entries, probably via `join(" - ")`.

I'd also recommend passing `myObject` into `count` as an argument rather than using it directly:

Live example:

```js
const myObject = { "first": ["x","y", "z"], "second": ["a", "b"], "third": ["c"] }
const string = "String!";
const count = (obj) => {
  const result = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) =>
    `${key} ${value.length > 1 ? ("x " + value.length) : ""} (${value})`
  );
  return result;
};
console.log(string + " " + count(myObject).join(" - "));
```

Or if you wanted to do it *within* `count`, also pass in `string`:

```js
const myObject = { "first": ["x","y", "z"], "second": ["a", "b"], "third": ["c"] }
const string = "String!";
const count = (obj, str) => {
  const result = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) =>
    `${key} ${value.length > 1 ? ("x " + value.length) : ""} (${value})`
  );
  return `${str} ${result.join(" - ")}`;
};
console.log(count(myObject, string));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` method, and concat all values. It will be combination of `map and join`. The simplest among all APIs and faster.

```js
const count = (prefix, obj) => {
  const result = Object.entries(obj).reduce(
    (str, [key, value]) =>
      (str += ` ${key} ${
        value.length > 1 ? "X " + value.length : ""
      } (${value})`),
    prefix
  );
  return result;
};
const myObject = { first: ["x", "y", "z"], second: ["a", "b"], third: ["c"] };
const string = "String!";

console.log(count(string, myObject));
```

**Fastest among all[use for-in loop]:**

```js
const count = (obj, prefix = "") => {
  for (let key in obj) {
    let value = obj[key];
    prefix +=
      value && value.length > 1
        ? ` ${key} X ${value.length} (${value})`
        : ` ${key} (${value})`;
  }
  return prefix;
};
const myObject = { first: ["x", "y", "z"], second: ["a", "b"], third: ["c"] };
const string = "String!";

console.log(count(myObject, string));
```